# PHP Concurrent Requests Lead to Multiple Sessions

Tags: php, session, concurrency, request

I am working on a updating an existing visitor tracking script on a high traffic website. I noticed that there is a problem not with the script itself, but with what happens when there are multiple requests. Let's say a user double clicks on certain links to my site and there end up being two requests made at effectively the same time. Request 1 gets processed and a session is created. The script then proceeds to add a visitor record to the database. At the same time, request 2 is getting processed. It checks whether a session is set and there isn't, so it does the same thing as request 1 does. Now, we have 2 different sessions and 2 records in the visitors table in the database, when there should really be one. The session id for the current session ends up being from whichever request finished last.

So, what I'm looking to do is to prevent this from happening. Even if there are 100 multiple concurrent requests from the same visitor, I want there to be only one session id created and above all, only one record (not 100 records) inserted into the visitors table in the database. This involves determining in a matter of a few milliseconds that one request was already made. Any ideas?

Comment: And yes, we are certain we are having multiple concurrent requests. We have checked our server logs and we have double or even triple requests from the same visitor often the same second.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the beginning of your script to force a specific session. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I am talking about what happens when there are two concurrent requests. Whichever one of them is second doesn't know that the first one has already created a session. I need to figure out a way to change that. I don't have this problem with requests from the same visitor that occur after the first request has completed and sent back a response.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following workaround for my java application. When first accessing the php server I send a blocking ping call that establishes the unique session id. Afterwards I start my concurrent requests to the php server. This should also be possible from a web page for example in an init block.